# Extracting the list of supported image types in from a httpRequest?

Tags: c#, browser, httprequest

Is it possible from a httprequest, to extract the image types/mimes, that the client browser support.

I know that it is possible determine what the browser is, and the preferred image type, but not a list of all the supported.

It this even possible?

I am currently trying to optimize the mediahandling of my page, 
Webscore indicate that nextGen image should be served, as the once served now are too big.

Serving nextgen is not that difficult, currently is all the nextgen version not supported by all the browsers, and support list is currently hardcoded in a switch case. It would be neat if the client browser could provide me with info regarding what it supports, rather than having a list that very likely might become outdated due to updates.

This is why I am seeking for browser media format compatibility list from the mediaRequest been sent.

Comment: This feels like a XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills elaborated on the XY confusion..

Comment: What do you mean by "nextGen image"? As far as I know, the web standards for images has had no significiant changes for a very long time and nothing is expected in the pipeline that is considered a breaking change.

Comment: What are the image types that you want to serve? Why would you pick one over the other? If you want to optimize for speed and space you could save images as jpg and [set the quality to 90](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level). That will give you good quality images and small size.

Comment: You could solve this scenario on client side by providing multiple image sources as described here: https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/ (you could create a custom html helper to generate the html).

Answer (score 1):

navigator.mimeTypes would only list you the browser supported types within the browser navigation scope at that time. For more reference;

[navigator.mimeTypes Explained](https://sideshowbarker.net/html-syntax-highlight/multipage/system-state.html#mime-type)

[browserContext Explained](https://sideshowbarker.net/html-syntax-highlight/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context)

As to my knowledge, there is no way of getting the browser specific full list with any existing api. Moreover, stack will not be compatible with other browsers as shown in compatibility diagram.

[navigator.mimeTypes compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/mimeTypes#Browser_compatibility)

Additionally, if getting the supported mime types through plugins collection of the browser (only supported on Chrome and Firefox) you can do something like;

```
var mimeCheck = function (type) 
{
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(navigator.plugins, function (supported, plugin) {
    return supported || Array.prototype.reduce.call(plugin, function (supported, mime) {
                return supported || mime.type == type;
            }, supported);
        }, false);
}
```